# function that takes user input and adds it to an array

Tags: c, arrays

I have a homework problem to finish this method. I don't really know what to do. given this psuedocode can someone help me write this method?

```
/*
    make a new array of the old size plus the new size
    copy from the old to the new
    add the new characters
    don't forget to clean up the old array (free it)
    before you leave this function
*/

char * add(char * array, int num)
{
    return array;

}
```

Comment: It is not clear what is the new size? Perhaps that needs to be passed as an function argument as well? What are the new characters to be added to the new array?

Comment: does your function signature have to be `char * add(char * array, int num)`?

Comment: yea it has to have that signature

Answer (score 1):

As this is C, take a look at [realloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) - but you will need to also have a parameter for the old size (or perhaps use `strlen`)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pseudo code:

```
char * add(char * old_array, int old_size, char *additions, int new_size)
{
    malloc new_size bytes and assign to new_array
    memcpy old_size bytes from old_array into the new_array
    add additions into new_array starting from (new_array+old_size)
    free the old_araray
    return new_array;

}
```

Comment: @EdHeal, from the OP "don't forget to clean up the old array (free it)"

Comment: realloc sorts the copying and freeing (if required) out for you.

Comment: Give the teacher two solutions and point our relloc would be a better method - as it will be quicker