# adding new characters to new array based off old array malloc, realloc

Tags: c, arrays, char, malloc, realloc

i asked a previous question on this website and it got answered using pseudo code, yet I still cant figure out how to properly solve this problem

basically i pass an array of characters, and a number that the user selects that correlates to how many new characters to add to the array. I want to create a new array with size = the old array + the new number of characters to add, prompt user for the new chars, and then add it to the new array (with the old chars in it reallocated). I dont know how to do this! and am frustrated.

```
char * add(char * array, int num)
{
 /* malloc new_size bytes and assign to new_array
memcpy old_size bytes from old_array into the new_array
add additions into new_array starting from (new_array+old_size)
free the old_araray
return new_array; 
*/

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: possible duplicate of [function that takes user input and adds it to an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706828/function-that-takes-user-input-and-adds-it-to-an-array)

Comment: The function will need the old size, too. Otherwise it would not know how much to copy.

Comment: i figured i could call something like array.length and assign an int variable called oldsize, or strlen(array) something like that.

Comment: You're not actually passing an array, you're passing a pointer.  That doesn't carry any length information.  If the length can't be determined from the data it points to (e.g. with `strlen()` for a null-terminated string), you need to pass the length as a separate argument.

Comment: i think ill make a global variable at the top of my program that = the size of the original array. and just pass that in to the method.

Comment: Is the array itself a global variable?  If not, putting its size in a global variable is a bad idea.  You could have two different arrays with different lengths, but only one variable (the global) to keep track of the length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tagged the question "realloc" so presumably you're aware of the `realloc()` function.  It'd be simpler, and possibly more efficient, to use that instead of `malloc()`, `memcpy()`, and `free()`

What I don't see here, though, is how the function knows the size of the "old" array.  Is it a null-terminated string?  If not, you'll need to pass another integer that says how big the existing array is.

Assuming it's a null-terminated string, you could do something like this:

```
char *add(char *string, int num) {
  // Note, these represent the length *without* the null terminator...
  int old_length = strlen(string);
  int new_length = old_length + num;

  // ...so we add 1 here to make room for the null.
  string = realloc(string, new_length + 1);  // Error checking omitted

  for (int n = old_length; n < new_length; n += 1) {
    // Prompt for the new characters; here I'll just assume they're all 'X'.
    char new_char = 'X';

    string[n] = new_char;
  }

  string[new_length] = '\0';

  return string;
}
```

If it's not a null-terminated string, you'd pass in `old_length` as an argument rather than determining it with `strlen()`, don't add 1 in the `realloc()` call, and don't set `string[new_length]` to a null at the end.  The rest stays the same.